# How can I store keys in csv file of a dictionary if keys are list?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

These output is stored in csv file:

```
go:[u'forward', u'always', u'somewhere', u'very', u'now', u'somewhere', u'up']
incorrect:[u'little']
hide:[u'somewhere']
had:[u'little']
jiggle: [u'forward', u'little', u'little']
```

This is an output of a program. I got this from:

```
for a in consolidated:
    print a, consolidated[a]
    writer2.writerow([a, consolidated[a]])
```

Now when I want to retrieve the values, it creates problem.
        eg,

```
for i in consolidated[a]:
     print i
```

It doesn't give the values of the keys. How can I retrieve each values of the keys?

Or how can I store it like this:

```
(go,u'forward', u'always', u'somewhere', u'very', u'now', u'somewhere', u'up')
```

Comment: That's not "CSV" by any stretch of the imagination...!?

Comment: Yeah, but there should a way/trick . May be using some other way.

Comment: Programming isn't "trickery". The CSV file format can express rows and columns of values. Is that what you need? Perhaps not. Perhaps JSON would suit you better to express key-value maps and lists of values.

Comment: Why not just store it like `go, forward, always, somewhere, very, now, somewhere, up`? Why do you want the parentheses and the `u''` stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dictionary `d` with keys `go`,`incorrect`, and `had` etc. and their values are lists, it can be written to file as:

```
s='' 
for k,v in d.items():
    s += "{},{}\n".format(k,','.join(v))
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Note that the key would then correspond to the first string on each line, eg. `go,forward,always,...\nincorrect,little` etc.

A csv should have the same amount of values/commas on each line, and is therefore maybe not what you want if you have a variable length list you want to save to file.
To then retrieve the data you could do something like this:

```
d={}
with open('myfile.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words=line.split(',')
        d[words[0]] = words[1:]
```

If you need to format as unicode you could use something like `codecs.open(file,'w','utf-8')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming you have a dictionary with array values and you want to store them as csv in this format: `"key", "val1,val2,val3"` -- where `"` is the csv quoting character, and `,` is the delimeter.

This is how you store and read.

```
import csv

options = {
    "delimiter" : ",",
    "quotechar" : "\"",
    "quoting"   : csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
}

def create(dic, filename):
    data = []
    for key, values in dic.items():
        data.append([key, options['delimiter'].join(values)])

    with open(filename, 'wb') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, **options)
        for line in data:
            spamwriter.writerow(line)

def readFile(filename, _unicode=False):
    data = {}
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, **options)
        for row in spamreader:
            values = row[1].split(options['delimiter'])
            if _unicode:
                values = [unicode(value) for value in values]
            data[row[0]] = values
    return data


d = {
    "Hello" : ['aa','bb','cc','dd'],
    "World" : ['e','f','g','h']
}

filename = "dataFile.csv"
create(d, filename)

# print as strings
print readFile(filename)
print readFile(filename, True)
```

This will output the following:

```
# string values
{
    'World': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 
    'Hello': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
}
# unicode values
{
    'World': [u'e', u'f', u'g', u'h'], 
    'Hello': [u'aa', u'bb', u'cc', u'dd']
}
```

and when you open the csv file, this is how it looks:

[image: CSV File]